# Testing lifecyle in Go. Is it possible to add tear up and down method without duplication of code?

Tags: go, testing

I started working with Go a month go. I come from java/kotlin background and I would like to understand if it's possible to achieve some of the same stuff that I did in those languages even in Go.

My current problem is this one.

I have a set of integration test cases where I need to initialize some stuff and then clean the resources: a common use case, I believe.

Here's some pseudo code of what I want achieve, if possible:

```
for each test {
  init resources
  run test {
     init test resources
     execute method under test
     assert
  }
  clean resources
}
```

At the moment, what I could try, was this approach:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup()
    code := m.Run() 
    shutdown()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

Which is fine generally speaking if not that it runs at package level. That doesn't give me much control at the moment because I would like to run one of those per test files. (that's what I noticed at least, please let me know if I'm wrong about it)

At the moment what I'm doing is basically run initialization for each test, but that's really a lot of duplicated code:

```
address, tearDownTestCase := testutils.SetupTestCase(emptyContext, postRouter(login.LoginUser), "/login")
defer tearDownTestCase()
// init test use case data
// run test
// clean use case data
```

Do you think there is a better approach?

Comment: testify https://github.com/stretchr/testify has a fixture system

Comment: Your current approach is idiomatic. If the setup really is the same for all tests, consider [table driven test](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests).

Comment: @Peter yes, it's the same for all test but table driven approach doesn't allow me to express what's the test is about. If I can keep single tests I'll have the test name that describes it. Especially in integration tests where more things happen under the hood, I prefer keeping the tests separated.

Comment: Go has [subtests](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks) for descriptive related names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not have the inbuilt functionality to support tear up and down methods. However, there are multiple third-party packages that enable this. Out of all of these, I like the [ginkgo](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo) package the most. It is very expressive and avoids code duplication.

A sample test would look like

```
var _ = Describe("Book", func() {
    var (
        longBook  Book
        shortBook Book
    )

    BeforeEach(func() {
        longBook = Book{
            Title:  "Les Miserables",
            Author: "Victor Hugo",
            Pages:  1488,
        }

        shortBook = Book{
            Title:  "Fox In Socks",
            Author: "Dr. Seuss",
            Pages:  24,
        }
    })

    Describe("Categorizing book length", func() {
        Context("With more than 300 pages", func() {
            It("should be a novel", func() {
                Expect(longBook.CategoryByLength()).To(Equal("NOVEL"))
            })
        })

        Context("With fewer than 300 pages", func() {
            It("should be a short story", func() {
                Expect(shortBook.CategoryByLength()).To(Equal("SHORT STORY"))
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Similarity there are other lifecycle methods like `afterEach`, `justBeforeEach` etc.